# Making A DCT in a for loop faster

Tags: swift, vdsp

I need to run a DCT on multiple signals (time slices of the same audio signal).

My current code looks like this:

```
var ci = Array(stride(from: Float(0), to: Float(y.count), by: Float(p)))

var c = Array<Float>(repeating:0.0, count:y.count)

for (index,value) in ci.enumerated() {

    var i = index
    var v = Int(value)
    var newArray = Array(y[v...(v+Int(p)-1)])

    let DCTSetup = vDSP_DCT_CreateSetup(nil, vDSP_Length(newArray.count), vDSP_DCT_Type.II)

    var nac = Array<Float>(repeating:0.0, count:newArray.count)
    vDSP_DCT_Execute(DCTSetup!, &newArray, &nac)

    //c.append(contentsOf: nac)
    c.insert(contentsOf: nac, at: v)
}

//c.removeFirst()
```

But this is taking ages. So for a 10 second audio sample it takes well over 60 seconds.

Is there a way of doing a DCT on multiple signal quickly? (I have made up an array of each sample appended to the other for this computation).

Hope you can help,

Best,

Feras A.

Comment: try having the line

    'let DCTSetup = vDSP_DCT_CreateSetup(nil, vDSP_Length(newArray.count), vDSP_DCT_Type.II)'


outside the for loop.

Comment: Have you timed your calls?  I.e., I expect you spend most of your time in vDSP_DCT_Execute() but do you know the time spent elsewhere?  Have you verified that you have the appropriate number of loops?    If that shows no possible savings, you will need to redo your overall method/algorithm for what you want to solve.

Comment: Thanks Yohst. I will time them all and get back to here.